# Removing the reference to a user control in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a wpf application which has a main window and menu. This main window has a panel, and on clicking the menu item i create an instance of the user control and load the panel with the control.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="" MinHeight="750" Height="Auto" MinWidth="1100" Width="Auto" WindowState="Maximized" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        Loaded ="MainWindow_OnLoaded" Closing="Window_Closing">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility ="Auto" SizeChanged="ScrollViewer_SizeChanged">
        <Grid Width="Auto">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="38"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Height="38" Width="Auto" Background="#09527B">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="189"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Expander Name="test" Header="Admin" Foreground="White" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                            <StackPanel  Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                <Expander Header="Data" Foreground="White">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="Add/Edit UC1" Foreground="White" Margin="30,5,0,0" MouseDown="OpenUC1_MouseDown" MouseEnter="TextBlock_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="TextBlock_MouseLeave"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="Add/Edit UC2" Name="tbxBuild" Foreground="White" Margin="30,5,0,0" MouseDown="OpenUC2_MouseDown" MouseEnter="TextBlock_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="TextBlock_MouseLeave"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Expander>                               
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid Name="pnlMain" Height ="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
private void OpenUC1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
for (int i = 0; i < pnlMain.Children.Count; i++ )
            {
                pnlMain.Children.Remove(pnlMain.Children[i]);

            }
using (UC2 _uc2= new UC2())
            {
                pnlMain.Children.Add(_uc2);
            }
}

private void OpenUC2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
for (int i = 0; i < pnlMain.Children.Count; i++ )
            {
                pnlMain.Children.Remove(pnlMain.Children[i]);

            }
using (UC1 _uc1= new UC1())
            {
                pnlMain.Children.Add(_uc1);
            }
}
```

My question is when I remove the control(UC1) from the main panel, when will that control be disposed?
Both the user control(UC1 and UC2) has the same view model attached to its data context. So i find that some of the methods in the removed user control(UC1) is called even though that is removed from the panel. The reason being, when a new instance of UC2 is created, there are some changes in the data model which in effect calls the dependent methods in UC1.
But if UC1 had been disposed this wouldn't happen. How can I make sure UC1 is disposed before instance of UC2 is created?

```
public UC1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            this.DataContext = App.ViewModel.TestViewModel;
        }

 private void UC1_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DataContext = null;
        }


public UC2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
            this.DataContext = App.ViewModel.TestViewModel;
        }

 private void UC2_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.DataContext = null;
        }
```

The unloaded method is not called immediately when the control is removed from the panel.

Comment: This question is unclear. "Disposed" has a very specific meaning in the context of .NET/C#: "to have the object's `IDisposable.Dispose()` method called". You don't seem to be dealing with `IDisposable` here, so the use of the term "disposed" is incorrect and misleading. In general, the `Unloaded` event should be raised _"when the element is removed from within an element tree of loaded elements"_, as MSDN says. But without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's hard to say why it's not in your case

Answer (score 0):

Quote from an [MSDN forum entry](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ee9672ed-a991-4dc1-9c92-a015ca2d99d3/when-exactly-are-the-loaded-unloaded-events-raised?forum=wpf) about **Loaded/Unloaded** events:

> The events are raised asynchronously, so there might be some delay
>   between the action that causes the event and the event itself.   The
>   events are effectively put into a list and a task is added to the
>   dispatcher's queue.  When that task runs, it raises the events on the
>   list.

So the answer is you can't predict when exactly these events will raised and you shouldn't expect that they will be called immediately after you removed a control from it's parent.

It's kinda difficult to give you a proper solution without seeing the full project, but here's a quick and dirty solution: rather than making sure that the given user controls' events are fired in time let's check the **Parent property** of the UC1/UC2 object before running the method. If the property is null then the UC1/UC2 object was removed and you should not execute that method.

But let me point out some problems with this code:

- What's the point of the using block in the MouseDown event handlers? You create a user control object, add it to the panel and then immediately after that you call the Dispose method on it? (that's what the using block does in C#)
- You don't need a for loop to remove all the children elements from a Panel control like a Grid. You can do that in one line. `pnlMain.Children.Clear();`

Comment: _"A ViewModel should not store references to View objects in an MVVM application"_ -- while I agree with that statement, could you elaborate on what _specifically_ in the code the OP provided concerns you in that respect? It is normal for view models to have _implicit_ references to view objects, via data binding, and it was my assumption that was all that was going on in the OP's situation. I.e. changing a property value in the view model invoked some method in the assumed-discarded `UserControl` object. Is there an explicit reference from VM to view in the OP's post that I overlooked?

Comment: "The reason being, when a new instance of UC2 is created, there are some changes in the data model which in effect calls the dependent methods in UC1". I assumed that "calls the dependent methods in UC1" meant a direct call of the method, by holding a reference to UserControl object. But you're right, I shouldn't make such assumption without seeing the rest of the code, I'll remove that part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When I write and test code to dynamically add and remove a `UserControl` object from a window's visual tree, I find that the `Unloaded` event is raised just as expected.

In your own code example, there is at least one serious problem, and two incongruities:

1. The serious problem is how you are removing children. Your `for` loop is iterating by index through the children of the `pnlMain` object (a `Grid`). **But removing any child invalidates the sequence of indexes!** That is, the loop will first remove the child at index 0; this causes the child at index 1 to now become the child at index 0. But the loop increments the index before continuing, and will next remove the child at index 1. This child was originally at index **2**. The code skips every other child (i.e. the ones originally at odd-numbered indexes), leaving half of them attached as children of the `Grid`.
2. Incongruity #1: I would expect a method with the phrase "OpenUC1" in the name to add an instance of `UC1`. However, your `OpenUC1_MouseDown()` method seems to be adding an instance of `UC2` (and vice a versa for `OpenUC2_MouseDown()`). At the very least, there should be a comment in the code explaining why the code is different from what one might expect given the name of the method.
3. Incongruity #2: there is a `using` statement around the call to `Add()` when adding the `UserControl` objects. First, `UserControl` itself does not implement `IDisposable`, so unless your types have implemented that interface, that code is not even legal. Second, even if your `UserControl` subclasses *do* implement that interface, it does not seem like a very good idea to me to *dispose* an object that you've just created and which you are retaining in the visual tree (i.e. by adding it to the `Grid`'s children).

Unfortunately, as I mentioned in my comment, without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces your problem, it is impossible to say why your code does not behave as one would hope and/or expect it to. It is *possible* that any of the above points (but especially #1) are the cause of the behavior you're seeing, but I have no way to know for sure.

If after addressing those issues (or determining somehow that they are not problems…though if you can legitimately do that, I would argue that the code is still defective, in the sense that it's poor design), you find that your problem still exists, please edit your question so that it includes a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example that reliably reproduces the problem.

In the meantime, here is a simple code example that illustrates the basic behavior of the `Unloaded` event being raised just as expected when the object is removed from the visual tree. Note that while the correct way to remove all children from the `Grid` object's `Children` collection is to simply call the `Clear()` method (e.g. `pnlMain.Children.Clear()`), I have included an example of a explicit loop-based approach that does work.

### XAML:

#### UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestSO33289488UserControlUnloaded.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Unloaded="UserControl_Unloaded"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="UserControl" FontSize="36"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO33289488UserControlUnloaded.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Add UserControl"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <Grid x:Name="grid1"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

### C#:

#### UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestSO33289488UserControlUnloaded
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("UserControl.Unloaded was raised");
        }
    }
}
```

#### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace TestSO33289488UserControlUnloaded
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private bool _removeUserControl;

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_removeUserControl)
            {
                //grid1.Children.Clear();

                // Calling Clear() is better, but if you really want to loop,
                // it is possible to do correctly. For example:
                while (grid1.Children.Count > 0)
                {
                    grid1.Children.RemoveAt(grid1.Children.Count - 1);
                }

                button1.Content = "Add UserControl";
            }
            else
            {
                grid1.Children.Add(new UserControl1());
                button1.Content = "Remove UserControl";
            }

            _removeUserControl = !_removeUserControl;
        }
    }
}
```